# Unknown type name for UIViewController class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a subclassed `UIView` called `TestView.h` below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TestsViewController.h"

@interface TestView : UIView

// To get the navigation controller parent clas
@property (nonatomic, retain) TestsViewController *parent;
```

> Line above causes error: Unknown type name TestViewController: did you mean CostViewController

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andObjects:(PFObject *)objects;

@end
```

And I have the `TestsViewController.h` below:

```
#import "CostViewController.h"
#import "TesView.h"

@interface TestsViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate, CostViewControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>

@end
```

And in the implementation file I have for `TestsViewController.m` I call this:

```
TestView *tests = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andObjects:replies];
tests.parent = self;
```

But the line above gives an error:

> Incompatiable pointer types assigning to CostsViewController * from TestsViewController *

What is wrong with this?

`CostViewController.h` is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

@class CostViewController;

@protocol CostViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

// Functions for delegate

@end

@interface CostViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, MBProgressHUDDelegate>
{
    MBProgressHUD *HUD;
    MBProgressHUD *refreshHUD;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CostViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Thanks.

Comment: What/where is CostViewController?

Comment: Try @class TestsViewController instead of #import.

Answer (score 4):

This may be due to circular Import. 
Replace #import "TestsViewController.h" with @class TestsViewController

Answer (score 0):

Instead of below code you may used loadView method in TestsViewController.m -

```
TestView *tests = [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andObjects:replies];
tests.parent = self;

-(void)loadView
{
  self.view= [[TestView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andObjects:replies];
}
```

Hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have typo in your code.

> @property (nonatomic, retain) Test**s**ViewController

and

> Unknown type name TestViewController:

What is your class name? Test or Tests ?
And the same situation with other class

> @interface CostViewController

and

> Incompatiable pointer types assigning to Cost**s**ViewController